# Core Data: Automatically Trim String Properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

For my Core Data `NSManagedObject`, I would like to ensure any `NSString` properties only contain strings that have been trimmed of whitespace.

I'm aware that I could achieve this by overriding each setter method, like so:

```
- (void)setSomeProperty:(NSString *)someProperty
{
    someProperty = [someProperty stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    if ((!someProperty && !self.someProperty) || [someProperty isEqualToString:self.someProperty]) return;

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"someProperty"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:someProperty forKey:@"someProperty"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"someProperty"];
}
```

However, this seems like a lot of code to have to write, especially since my managed object is likely to have quite a few `NSString` properties.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a custom `NSValueTransformer` for `NSString` and assign all of your `NSString` properties to the new transformer in the model editor:

```
@interface StringTransformer: NSValueTransformer {}
@end

@implementation StringTransformer
+ (Class)transformedValueClass { 
  return [NSString class]; 
}

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation { 
    return YES;
}

- (id)transformedValue:(id)value {
    return value;
}

- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value {
    return [value stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this as the answer because it has the benefit of ensuring the property value is always trimmed. The other solution is good too (overriding `willSave`), but has the drawback that the property value remains untrimmed until such time as a save is performed.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to ensure that the saved data is trimmed then you can implement `willSave` and use `changedValues` to check only the changed values. This will also make it easy to do in a loop to minimise code duplication.

Comment: And if you need to do this before saving, probably the easiest thing to do is implement a method for that specific purpose. Something like a `trimStringProperties` method that runs through each string attribute and trims each one.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it during property validation:

```
- (BOOL)validateSomeProperty:(id *)inOutValue error:(NSError **)error
{
    if (inOutValue)
    {
        NSString *value = *inOutValue;
        *inOutValue = [value stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

[Core data will automatically call `validateSomeProperty:error:` before saving your record](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdValidation.html), so this will make sure that any data that gets saved is trimmed.  It won't stop the on-change events firing if someone changes it from, say, `foo` to `\n\nfoo\n\n`, but it does mean that you don't have to fire them by hand.

Comment: Thank you, this is another good option. I wasn't aware you could actually change a property value during validation.

Comment: Changing the values in the validation method is strongly discouraged as mentioned in the Apple Doc, because it makes the context dirty and the validation can be called again, causing the infinite loop.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/ObjectValidation.html